# How to count array empty values with php?

Tags: php, arrays

How to calculate the numbers of arrays whose values are empty.
For example, I have array result:

```
    Array (
       [0] => 'A',
       [1] => 'B',
       [2] => 'C',
       [3] => '',
       [4] => '',
       [5] => 'F',
       [6] => '')
```

Here are 3 empty array values (index 3,4,6), so how the way get the number of empty array values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$c = 0;
foreach($a as $v) {
    if ($v === '') { 
        $c++;
    }
}
echo "count: $c\n";
```

-- OR --

```
$t = array_count_values($a);
echo "count: {$t['']}\n";
```

PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 3):

For multi-dimensional arrays (and flat arrays too) you can use

```
 $a =  Array (
   0 => 'A',
   1 => 'B',
   2 => 'C',
   3 => '',
   4 => '',
   5 => 'F',
   6 => '',
   7 => ['','']
  );

$total = 0;

array_walk_recursive($a, function($i) use (&$total){
 if($i === '') ++$total;
});

echo $total;
```

Output

```
5
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07996e86041d7e23661829bfefabf9630f4847e4)

Probably the shortest way is this:

```
echo count(array_intersect($a, ['']));
```

But it doesn't work with nested arrays

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b57c59e351ebc4e15335f662eaaff80d12920ce5)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = ['1', '2', '', '', '5', ''];
echo count($a) - count(array_filter($a)); // output: 3
```

Comment: you can improve your answer by adding intention of your code

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Thank you, but I think this code is too simple and clear at a glance

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes, if only statistics ''

Comment: `array_filter()` is greedy and in a few scenarios it will return inaccurate results due to falsey, zeroish, null values.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
for ($i =0; $i < length($array); $i++) {
  if ($array[$i] == '')
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)